# Executing function before every controller request

Tags: laravel, http-token-authentication, laravel-controller

I'm calling cloud APIs using token authentication with [php-openstack-sdk](https://php-openstack-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/compute/v2/servers.html#listing-servers).

```php
$openstack = new OpenStack\OpenStack([
    'authUrl' => '{authUrl}',
    'region' => '{region}',
    'user' => [
        'id' => '{userId}',
        'password' => '{password}'
    ],
    'scope' => ['project' => ['id' => '{projectId}']]
]);
```

However, every API call requires me to be authenticated (as shown in the code above). Instead of repeating the same auth code in every controller function, how do I do it once and be able to call `$openstack` in my controller's functions? i.e., in my controller, I can directly use $openstack.

```php
public function listServers() 
{
    $openstack->computeV2()->listServers();
}
```

Comment: Do you need to call the auth code before every method of one controller or for all the controllers? Put that code in a `__construct()`. If you need it for every controller, user the parent `__construct()`. I assume your controllers extend the base `Controller`.

Comment: Undefined variable $openstack https://pastebin.com/rbwCXikF

Comment: You should try middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the logic in the `__construct()` of your `Controller.php` if you want that to be accessible for all the controllers. If not, write the `__construct()` within the controller you need.

Controller.php

```php
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected $openstack;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->openstack = new OpenStack\OpenStack([
            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

NetworkController.php

```php
class NetworkController extends Controller
{
    public function getNetworkDetails() {
        $network = $this->openstack->networking();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use [laravel middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware)

Answer (score 0):

You can place the code shown in the `__construct` function of your controller and provide it as a protected variable to the class.

Comment: You need to provide it as a protected variable of the class, then you can use it as `$this->openstack`